# How to extract the first element of list and use it to replace list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The original HTML codes are like this:

```
<div>
<ul class="alt">
   <li> <a class="button1"> Button1 </a></li>
   <li> <a class="button2"> Button2 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And then I'd like to change it to this:

```
<div>
  <a class="button1"> Button1 </a>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to implement this in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get fist elemnt by either `.first()` or `:first Selector`

```
$('div').html($('div li:first').html())
```

or try

```
$("div").html($('li').first().html());
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhpWp/)

Comment: I think your second example is preferred, as it uses a jQuery method and doesn't require more processing on the selector itself. Something that probably wouldn't be noticed, but just something to think about. Either obviously work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JudBH/3/)**

```
$('.alt').closest('div').html($('.alt li:first').html());
```

`Its better to assign some id to div you are intending to make it unique`, so that the changes you make are limited to this div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
<ul class="alt">
   <li> <a class="button1"> Button1 </a></li>
   <li> <a class="button2"> Button2 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#div1').html($('#div1 li:first').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this :)

```
$('.alt').replaceWith( $('.alt>li:eq(0)').contents() );
```

Or just for fun:

```
$('.alt>li:eq(0)').unwrap().siblings().remove().end().contents().unwrap();
```